# Python String replacement in a file each time gives different result

Tags: json, string, python-3.x, replace

I have a JSON file and I want to do some replacements in it. I've made a code, it works but it's wonky.

This is where the replacement gets done.

```
replacements1 = {builtTelefon:'Isim', builtIlce:'Isim', builtAdres:'Isim', builtIsim:'Isim'}
replacements3 = {builtYesterdayTelefon:'Isim', builtYesterdayIlce:'Isim', builtYesterdayAdres:'Isim', builtYesterdayIsim:'Isim'}

with open('veri3.json', encoding='utf-8') as infile, open('veri2.json', 'w') as outfile:
for line in infile:
    for src, target in replacements1.items():
        line = line.replace(src, target)
    for src, target in replacements3.items():
        line = line.replace(src, target)
    outfile.write(line)
```

Here's some examples to what `builtAdres` and `builtYesterdayAdres` looks like:

```
01 Temmuz 2018 Pazar.1
30 Haziran 2018 Cumartesi.1
```

I run this on my data but it results in many different outputs each time. Please do check the screenshot below because I don't know how else I can tell about it.

This is the very same code and I run the same thing everytime but it results in with different outcomes each time.

[image: imgur mirror of the problem]

Here is the original JSON file:

[image: imgur mirror of original file]

What it should do is testing entire file against `01 Temmuz 2018 Pazar` and if it finds just replaces it with string `Isim` without touching anything else. On a second run checks if anything is `30 Haziran 2018 Cumartesi` and replaces them with string `Isim` too.

What's causing this?

### Example files for re-testing:

[pastebin - veri3.json](https://pastebin.com/qg603d0b)

[pastebin - code.py](https://pastebin.com/fL8y7ai9)

Comment: I've added these two lines before the `replacements1` part. `replacements1 = collections.OrderedDict()` `replacements3 = collections.OrderedDict()` Still some of the fields sometimes disappearing. (Like `01 Temmuz 2018 Pazar.2` part should've said `Isim.2` but entire part is gone again)

Comment: Could you please create a smaller test case that reveals the problem as well? Without your JSON file it's not possible to reproduce the issue on our side.

Comment: @user8035311 I'll post both the complete code and the json file of today now, editing question. Edit: I've added the json file and the python code I'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have just one problem: you're trying to use "Isim" as key name multiple times within the same object, and this will botch the JSON.
The reason why you might be "getting different results" might have to do with the client you're using to display the JSON. I think that if you look at the raw data, the JSON should have been fully altered (I ran your script and it seems to be altered). However, the client will not handle very well the repeated key, and will display all objects as well as it can.
In fact, I'm not sure how you get "Isim.1", "Isim.2" as keys, since you actually use "Isim" for all. The client must be trying to cope with the duplicity there.

Try this code, where I use "Isim.1", "Isim.2" etc.:

```
replacements1 = {builtTelefon:'Isim.3', builtIlce:'Isim.2', builtAdres:'Isim.1', builtIsim:'Isim'}
replacements3 = {builtYesterdayTelefon:'Isim.3', builtYesterdayIlce:'Isim.2', builtYesterdayAdres:'Isim.1', builtYesterdayIsim:'Isim'}
```

I think you should be able to have all the keys displayed now.

Oh and PS: to use your code with my locale I had to change line 124 to specify 'utf-8' as encoding for the outfile:

```
with open('veri3.json', encoding='utf-8') as infile, open('veri2.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
```

Comment: This does solves the issue, I didn't realise that I was trying to rename all to the same. :( I use firefox quantom to view. It auto beautifes the json files to a readable format.

Thank you very much.